# Textview Before imageview in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout I am displaying image and on that image I am showing textview at bottom. Its work perfectly. my code is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="210dp"
android:padding="12dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:src="@mipmap/img_splash"/>

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNewsTitle"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />
```

Now I want to display One textview before this image (not on image) How to do this? I had tried but it is not display. When I use relativelayout then nothing is display. Please suggest me how to show textview before imageview in above code.

I also tried using relativelayout like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="210dp"
android:padding="12dp">

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTimeTitle"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:text="Last updated Time is:"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTimeTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:src="@mipmap/img_splash"/>

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNewsTitle"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />
```

Now First Textview displays before image which is what I want. But last (second) textview display below imageview I want it over imageview at bottom.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html. So if you need textview first then have textview above imageview in xml. RelativeLayout can also be used. It depends on what you want.

Comment: @Raghunandan  I dont want textview over imageview. I want texview below this textview my imageview and over this imageview one textview at bottom.

Comment: Using RelativeLayout would be a better option. Place textview relative to imageview

Comment: @Raghunandan  please check my edited question. I tried using relativelayout. But now second textview is not display over imageview. it is display below imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Relativelayout as suggest by Raghunandan works .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="210dp"
android:padding="12dp">

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTimeTitle"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:text="Last updated Time is:"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTimeTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:src="@mipmap/img_splash"/>

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:id="@+id/textViewNewsTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="240dp"

android:padding="12dp">

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTimeTitle"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:text="Last updated Time is:"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTimeTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:src="@mipmap/img_splash"/>

<com.mynews.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewNews"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNewsTitle"
    android:background="#CCd3d3d3"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text_color" />
```